# Google App Script - how to set date with timezone in AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get()

Tags: date, timezone, report

I'm using Apps Script and trying to extract data from `AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get('all', 'the date')` (to get classroom last interaction timestamps), but it always comes with records from another day. For example, if I extract from the 5th, the report brings the 6th together, until 7 o'clock in the morning.

The date parameter is a string and in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/userUsageReport/get?hl=pt) says the following:

> Represents the date the usage occurred. The timestamp is in the ISO
> 8601 format, yyyy-mm-dd. We recommend you use your account's time zone
> for this.

But if the parameter is a string in yyyy-mm-dd format, how am I going to pass the date with the right time zone?

This code not work:

```
var myDate = new Date(2021,5,5);
var timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
var date = Utilities.formatDate(myDate, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

var page = AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get('all', date);
```

How do I use the date correctly?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are the report dates UTC?

Comment: I think so, and I don't know how to change it according to the region.

Answer (score 0):

If the report dates are UTC, then each may first be converted to JavaScript Date objects using

```
var myDate = new Date('report_date_string');
```

The second two lines of your code look like they should follow correctly in converting and formatting the Dates to strings in your local time zone.